# Оператор GROUP BY feild ASC не работает на MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, sql

Сайт стал большим и пришлось переезжать с хостинга на vps.

Запрос

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table` WHERE parent = 0 GROUP BY `feild` ASC
```

перестал работать, причем если поменять запрос на

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table` WHERE parent = 0 GROUP BY `feild` ORDER BY `feild` ASC
```

то все начинает работать.

Подскажите настройку MySQL что-бы не переписывать все подобные запросы.

---

vps: Ubuntu 20.04, MySQL Ver 8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.4

Comment: Что значит `перестал работать`? Ну и сам запрос **очень** странный. `SELECT * ... GROUP BY ...` по правилам SQL работать и не должен. Это только MySQL позволяет себе такие вольности

Comment: А такая конструкция `GROUP BY feild ASC` не могла работать никогда. А если и работала, то это больше похоже на баг сервера

Comment: Ваш вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к Ubuntu. Зато имеет прямое отношение к синтаксису SQL. Так что не стоит откатывать метки

Comment: Антон, это не баг сервера. В версии Mysql 5.7 данный запрос работает. А вот  в 8 версии mysql это пофиксили https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=8693. Вот я и спрашиваю про настройку mysql 8.

Comment: Вопрос имеет отношение к Ubuntu, потому что mysql стоит на Ubuntu

Comment: _потому что mysql стоит на Ubuntu_, а если на другой системе будет стоять, что-то измениится?

Comment: *Подскажите настройку MySQL что-бы не переписывать все подобные запросы.* Нет такой. Даже не надейтесь. Переписывайте...

Comment: И заодно `distinct * ... group by ...` тоже перепишите, тоже работать не будет.